# How to filter Apache virtual host listing using grep

Tags: apache, grep, virtual-hosts, piping

I have an Apache server configured with many virtual hosts and would like to be able to filter them using grep like so..

```
# httpd -S | grep "myStr"
```

.. however, this approach doesn't work - I'm still seeing all my virtual hosts listed. Any ideas how I can actually do this?

Here's a sample of the output from httpd -S

```
[root@224136 config]# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
184.22.xxx.33:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server default (/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/default.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost default (/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/default.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost webmail (/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/webmail.conf:6)
         port 80 namevhost xxxxxx.com (/home/httpd/xxxxxx.com/conf/kloxo.xxxxxxx.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost twptest.xxxxxx.com (/home/httpd/twptest.xxxxxx.com/conf/kloxo.twptest.xxxxxx.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost yyyyyyy.com (/home/httpd/yyyyyy.com/conf/kloxo.yyyyyyy.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost zzzzzzzz.com (/home/httpd/zzzzzzz.com/conf/kloxo.zzzzzzzz.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost expenses.zzzzzzzz.com (/home/httpd/expenses.zzzzzzz.com/conf/kloxo.expenses.zzzzzzz.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost aaaaaaaa.cz (/home/httpd/aaaaaaaaaaaa.cz/conf/kloxo.aaaaaaaaaaa.cz:4)
         port 80 namevhost aaaaaaaaaaa.cz (/home/httpd/aaaaaaaaaaaaa.cz/conf/kloxo.aaaaaaaaaa.cz:142)
```

Comment: can you post the output from `httpd -S` here (don't have it installed so I cannot test). grep operate on STDOUT, does `httpd -S` deliver to STDOUT? if not a redirection is needed...

Comment: well, it looks like it delivers to STDOUT. Can't post the whole output but here's some:

[root@224136 config]# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
184.22.xxx.xx:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server default (/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/default.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost default (/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/default.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost webmail (/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/webmail.conf:6)
         port 80 namevhost xoundesign.com (/home/httpd/xxxxxxxx.com/conf/kloxo.xxxxxxxx.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost twptest.xxxxxxxx.com (/home/httpd/........

Comment: please update your question instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that "I'm still seeing all my virtual hosts listed" I suspect you need to redirect STDERR to STDOUT as seen below (assuming bash) `out.py` is just a pythonscript that writes some output to STDERR using `sys.stderr.write()`

```
$ ./out.py | grep zzzzzzzz

VirtualHost configuration:
184.22.xxx.33:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server default (/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/default.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost default (/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/default.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost webmail (/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/webmail.conf:6)
         port 80 namevhost xxxxxx.com (/home/httpd/xxxxxx.com/conf/kloxo.xxxxxxx.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost twptest.xxxxxx.com (/home/httpd/twptest.xxxxxx.com/conf/kloxo.twptest.xxxxxx.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost yyyyyyy.com (/home/httpd/yyyyyy.com/conf/kloxo.yyyyyyy.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost zzzzzzzz.com (/home/httpd/zzzzzzz.com/conf/kloxo.zzzzzzzz.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost expenses.zzzzzzzz.com (/home/httpd/expenses.zzzzzzz.com/conf/kloxo.expenses.zzzzzzz.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost aaaaaaaa.cz (/home/httpd/aaaaaaaaaaaa.cz/conf/kloxo.aaaaaaaaaaa.cz:4)
         port 80 namevhost aaaaaaaaaaa.cz (/home/httpd/aaaaaaaaaaaaa.cz/conf/kloxo.aaaaaaaaaa.cz:142)
```

Now send STDERR to STDOUT:

```
$ ./out.py 2>&1 | grep zzzzzzzz
         port 80 namevhost zzzzzzzz.com (/home/httpd/zzzzzzz.com/conf/kloxo.zzzzzzzz.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost expenses.zzzzzzzz.com (/home/httpd/expenses.zzzzzzz.com/conf/kloxo.expenses.zzzzzzz.com:4)
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked perfectly, however I'm confused as to why the httpd -S command would write to STDERR and not STDOUT. It seems a bit illogical since the output is not an error - just a list of virtualhosts.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same need, and used the following:

```
 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S 2>&1 | awk '/namevhost/  {print $4;} '
```

It redirects SDTERR (2) into STDOUT (&1) before getting awk to clean it up